# Android Listview opening another Listview... SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

My app currently has a listview which when clicked opens another activity and saves the info into a database.
My problem is i would like to create another listview which is above the listview i have already created and when clicked start a new instance of the listview but how do i tackle this using SQLite? Do I create a new database each time a listview row is clicked?? Is there any examples or advice on how to tackle this? I've been searching for days.

Cheers

Comment: One database for your app is enough. But I don't understand your requirement. Please be more specific. ListView opens ListView points towards ExpandableListView but this is simply a guess.

Comment: Okay so currently one listview when clicked starts an activty which allows user input then attaches that to a listview row and creates a new row in the database table which is all good so far. But what i want is all the above to be attached to another list view so each row is able to start a fresh listview.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to solve it:

I have a ListView, with a CustomAdapter, and on the getView of the customAdapter, I have something like this:

```
LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.list_musics);
list.removeAllViews();

for (Music music : albums.get(position).musics) {
    View line = li.inflate(R.layout.inside_row, null);

    /* nested list's stuff */

    list.addView(line);
}
```

So, resuming, It's not possible to nest to ListViews, but you can create a list inside a row using LinearLayout and populating it with code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ExapandableListView. It might be what you want.

Comment: Very similar but i prefer rather then show children as an expandable listview, show them in a separate listviews after the list item has been clicked. I know how to achieve this with listviews im just not sure how to tackle saving the groups/child in the database?? Should i just add all the entries to the one table in my database and filter the rows depending on which group i would like to show or do i add a separate database table to each listview??